# Write a "Hello" interpreter

Tags: code-golf, interpreter, hello-world

### Background

Hello is a language "written" by [Anne Veling](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Anne_Veling), which errors if the program does not contain only `h`, and will print `Hello World` for every `h`

### Task

You are to write an interpreter/compiler for Hello.

### Example in Python

```
import os
i = input("Program: ")
for a in i:
    if a != 'h':
        print("err")
        quit()
    else:
        print("Hello World")
```

### Details

- If the program is not only `h`s, it must print `err` or `error` (case-insensitive)
- It's okay if you print "Hello World"s before your program discovers a non-`h` character and errors, however, the program must halt if a non-`h`
- You may throw an error, as long as you print `err`/`error` before throwing, or by using a custom error builtin, like `raise SyntaxError('err')` in python. (basically, you have to **purposefully** error with `err`/`error`
- Assume the program will not be empty
- Output can have a trailing newline, space, or nothing to separate `Hello World`s
- If a program has multiple lines, it should error (due to `\n` not being an `h`)
- You can assume that input will always be ASCII 33-126 and 10 (decimal)
- The `h`s are case sensitive (so `H` is not a valid program)
  instruction is found
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer wins

### Test cases

```
Input:

h

Output:

Hello World

Input:

hhhhhh

Output:

Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World

(again, it doesn't matter whether it's spaces, newlines, or nothing to separate `Hello World`s

Input:

rubbish

Output:

err

Input:

huh

Output:

Hello Worlderr

Or

err
```

First challenge so please have mercy

Comment: Is it acceptable to print `Hello World` to STDOUT and `err` to STDERR?

Comment: Yes, as long as you only print `err` when there is a non-`h` instruction.

Comment: Sorry for all the re-re-re-claification of the challenge. I am learning a lot due to this being my first question, so thank you for being nice!

Comment: Thank you for using the sandbox. I'd recommend leaving challenges there for at least a week, and even to advertise their imminent publishing in [TNB](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte), to lessen the risk of having to make changes after posting.

Comment: Are we allowed to print `err`/`error` as part of a larger error message?

Comment: Can we return a list of `Hello World`s?

Comment: In the case of an illegal program, is it acceptable to print ```err```/```error``` more than once, if this is the only thing that the interpreter prints?

Comment: Currently there are 2 kind of solutions: those which reproduce the sample code (for `hhxhh` outputs “Hello WorldHello Worlderr”) and those which only implement the written rules (for `hhxhh` outputs “err”). This is not good. Please clarify and add a relevant test case.

Comment: To amplify @manatwork's comment: **The given example Python program does not match the rules stated.** Given the input `hello world`, the example program would print `Hello worlderr` but the rules state it should print `err`.

Comment: @RossPresser "It's okay if you print "Hello World"s before your program discovers a non-`h` character and errors"

Comment: I never said it should print `err`, I said it could print `Hello Worlderr` *or* `err`

Comment: @Adam you can not return a list, nothing, spaces, or new lines only.

Comment: @the-cobalt "space" or "spaces"? Can I e.g. print `" HelloWorld  HelloWorld "`?

Comment: @Adam It must be "Hello World Hello World", so spaces

Comment: It's a great first challenge, though I agree with @manatwork that optionally allowing `Hello worlderr` or just `err` is two somewhat different implementations.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake

Comment: @640KB yeah, I never thought that would cause confusion, but thanks!

Comment: The example program does not just print `err` it prints a traceback which ends with `err`. Are `Err`, `Error`, `ERR`, etc. acceptable? Can they be a substring of the output (in which case your example could become `for a in input():print(1/(a=='h')*"Hello World")` [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFRITMPiApKSzQ0rQqKMvNKNAz1NRJtbdUz1DW1lDxSc3LyFcLzi3JSlDT//1fKyKjIyFACAA))?

Comment: The example program does indeed seem to be rather at odds with the rest of the description, but it's worth noting that almost all of the answers so far have used bytes to programmatically print 'err', rather than recycling their languages' inbuilt error messages.

Comment: (...it seems `ERR` etc. are acceptable "case-insensitive", but the rest of the question still stands.)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Fixed

Comment: What does "only if the exception raised is one of the aforementioned error messages (see example code)" mean?

Comment: "so in python..." - does not answer it - how does that translate to other languages?

Comment: Do we _have_ to output `/^err(or)?$/i` or can we _throw_ an error instead?

Comment: @Shaggy as long as when you throw the error, you purposefully output `/^err(or)?$/i`, either by printing it first, or by using a builtin function to throw a custom error, like `raise SyntaxError('err')` in python

Comment: @the-cobalt Personally, I also misread the challenge as requiring no hellos if there was a "syntax error" (lol). I suggest putting the relevant bullet point ("It's okay if you print "Hello World"s...") either directly after or merged with the bullet point explaining the error "handling". :) As you said, the spec is clear, but I think putting those two closer together would help make it more clear.

Comment: @CaptainMan done :)

Answer (score 26):

## [Lenguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage), \$1.42 \times 10^{122}\$ bytes

*minus a lot of bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen and Bubbler*

```
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh...
```

This is 142099843608359281286315447494338058415442968773543757980908246691462388164856076679905341690709953072132211450166077106439 `h`s, which also makes it a valid Hello program, though not one you'd want to run. The original brainfuck code is <s>140</s> 135 bytes:

```
,[>-[<-->-----]+<--[>]>[[-->-[>>+>-----<<]<--<---]>-.>>>+.>>..+++.>>.>.<<<.+++.------.<<-.[>]>>>>,>]<]<[[>++<+++++]>-.+++++++++++++..>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TUxJDoBACHsQwgtIP0I4qNGMMfHg@vwRxos9AF3osPfLNl/jWmtnYFNmcMIpToPDLCUD6DNUPRzNCFgQegwRorYhqtpIC3NQlqwJdPD4NQORUiIL6A8ReK2llKf053QfLw)

This prints Hello World every time it sees a `h` through a modification of the [shortest known Hello, World! program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163590/76162), stopping the loop and printing `err` if it sees anything other than a `h`.

Comment: The output of `Hello World` is supposed to be without exclamation mark in this challenge.

Comment: I think [this works](https://tio.run/##TYxLDoRACEQPhHACUhchLNTMpI2JC7/Hb6F14VsAVRQMaz8t/2Oca@0MbMoMTpxiNDjM0jKAnoWqx0YzAhaEH0WEqHWIqjbRwhyyhV46eJybgUgpyR/0RQReaynlKv3@O7cb), which should give 1/64 of the current score.

Comment: Technically this would actually be a polyglot.

Answer (score 14):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
lambda s:{*s}-{'h'}and'err'or'Hello World'*len(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcGxCoMwEADQ3a/IdongUNyE7v0DF5eERC5wXsIlIkX89iv0vfrtWHjW/b0p@SNEb9pyj@2ZbkB4PEdIIlAEPomomLUIRRgpsW1OL8yUzGupkrnb3WauZ7fOOcUB/wY5Q8gN9Qc)

**Python 2, 51 bytes**

```python
lambda s:s.strip('h')and'err'or'Hello World'*len(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcHBCsIwDADQ@76itzQeBD0OvPsHXgRpaUcKMS1Jx9jXR/C9cU7qcvft8XZO31xSsNWuNrWNCASYpEBVha7wrMw9vLpygQtXiYZ@UOMabuvQJjNuUdPxaTL2GRHRaaG/Rfecm5H/AA)

**Python 2, 51 bytes**

```python
lambda s:['err','Hello World'*len(s)]['h'+s==s+'h']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcaxCsIwEADQvV@R7RLromMhu3/g0BZJaMoFziTcpRS//hTf9NqnYy133f2iFN5xC0amGRIzXOGRiKp5VqYNLpSKFbfOgDCK9zL@suqJmZK5TY1z6Xa3HM5XLu3o1jmnOODfwEeMWVC/)

Answer (score 10):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 32 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
{'h'=⍵:'Hello World'⋄-⎕←'err'}⍤0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/6vVM9RtH/VutVL3SM3JyVcIzy/KSVF/1N2iC1QDVKGeWlSkXvuod4nB/zQg91Fv36Ou5ke9ax71bjm03vhR20SgsuAgZyAZ4uEZ/D9NAWgel7o6F4gBAkgcDxjbQx0A)

`{`…`}⍤0` replace each character (`⍵`) with the result of applying the following lambda to it:

`'h'=⍵:` if the character is `h`:

`'Hello World'` return the required phrase

`⋄` else:

`⎕←'err'` print `err`
  `-` negate it (causing an error and terminating)

Answer (score 10):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 76 bytes

```r
function(p,n=nchar(p))ifelse(p==strrep('h',n),strrep("Hello World",n),'err')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBDoAgDATvvsJwoU34And/4FmxBJOmkIrvR1ET97Qzya62RMzZt3hKqHsWKE68hLQoFMQ9Eh8ExfujqlIBm6wTdB@ZqY/HOStvpntLqhbfTzAGh6@lJz@vTDe1Cw)

Should be a comment on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210520/98085 - I didn't realise you could do functions like that! Slight change to be more robust when n = 0 and to use direct comparison rather than regex. -1 byte thanks to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90265/zippymagician.

Bonus version with side-effects (like redefining subtraction) thanks to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92901/dingus.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 71 bytes

```r
{`-`=strrep;function(p,n=nchar(p))`if`(p=='h'-n,'Hello world'-n,'err')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfkZqTk2/7vzpBN8G2uKSoKLXAOq00L7kkMz9Po0AnzzYvOSOxSKNAUzMhMy1Bo8DWVj1DXTdPR90DpE@hPL8oJwXMTy0qUteshRinoaSkyQVlZYABgp@Ukwrk/QcA)

Comment: Welcome to the site! I see you left a space between the last comma and `'err'`, so you should most likely remove that. Other than that, great answer!

Comment: This is a fantastic R golf, well done!  Your 71-byter can be shortened by defining ```-``` inside the function, which also removes the 'bonus' side-effect: [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##RcxBCoAgEAXQfacINzqgR5h9x7DMUJBRJqPjW1nQX/23@J9b8CllbNtBrsZMqmhCcmFmVUBbY3GvzL6AjZtVBVEGaUjL6ZmNZ@a0dntmCe@ZEgKGr4We30vyt9oF).

Comment: Good point @DominicvanEssen, thank you!

Comment: welcome to CCGC! You've come at the best time, [R is the language of the month for September!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19304/language-of-the-month-for-september-2020-r) Feel free to also join us in the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112541/the-r-project-for-statistical-golfing), and happy golfing :-)

Answer (score 7):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 23 characters

```
h=Hello World
?=err@end
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ echo -n 'hohoho' | gema 'h=Hello World;?=err@end'
Hello Worlderr
```

#### Gema (old version with err on empty code), 32 characters

```
\A\Z=err
h=Hello World
?=err@end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/P8PWIzUnJ18hPL8oJ4XL3ja1qMghNS8FKJEPggA) / [Try all test cases online!](https://tio.run/##nVDBSsQwED03XzGGuukeStSLBwmuB0FPghcPbVnaZtYWa1KSFIR1v70mKegqeNAcZl4mb2beS1PbbpbYDrVByG/AoXXbtrYoMpIUrGOVYHc4DBqetBkki8V4frz8E8aBZmqa3saJaAwja0JG0yu3A/YOp/n5mYWQL7/nCx9LxYDdq3FyPj@inYYAbt9GbB1KDx9eGCE7baAPJB@BpvuTT5fFpjrQK5CaJCZ2C5pmgG2nIQ/U2EX9Nq5Hx5/xtebWtBEAmztx5IRcCy9@g0rODNaUkOQPHryouIrzlPk7L0t1oL66iApo/6V5UVVFQgZFccQT4jdqVcFqtTgLnxIUSq1w/gA)

Comment: The table generating code is better than the actual code (JK, but seriously, nice table)

Comment: Do you use Gema as an awk replacement in your daily work?

Comment: @Jonah, unfortunately the practical usefulness of Gema is limited by the fact that it processes a piece of input only once. For example in this code I didn't had to worry because “h” matches both templates, as immediately after the first matching template was processed, the result was written out and a new cycle started by reading fresh input. But the real life problems usually require processing a piece of input in multiple steps, which is much more suitable for `sed`.

Answer (score 7):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>41</del> 40 bytes

Binary:

```
00000000: be82 00ba 1801 b409 ac3c 0d74 0a3c 6874  .........<.t.<ht
00000010: 02b2 24cd 2174 f1c3 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f  ..$.!t..Hello Wo
00000020: 726c 6424 6572 7224                      rld$err$
```

Listing:

```
BE 0082         MOV  SI, 82H            ; SI to DOS PSP 
BA 0118         MOV  DX, OFFSET HW      ; point to 'Hello World' string 
B4 09           MOV  AH, 9              ; DOS write string function 
            CHAR_LOOP: 
AC              LODSB                   ; AL = next input byte 
3C 0D           CMP  AL, 0DH            ; is a CR (end of input string)? 
74 0A           JZ   DONE               ; if so, end 
3C 68           CMP  AL, 'h'            ; is an 'h'? 
74 02           JZ   WRITE_STR          ; if so, write Hello(s)
B2 24           MOV  DL, LOW OFFSET ER  ; otherwise, point to 'err' string 
            WRITE_STR: 
CD 21           INT  21H                ; write string to stdout 
74 F1           JZ   CHAR_LOOP          ; if 'h', keep looping 
            DONE:
C3              RET                     ; return to DOS 
            HW  DB  'Hello World$'
            ER  DB  'err$'
```

Standalone PC DOS executable COM program.  Input via command line.  This version prints `Hello Worlderr` if an error is in the input code.

[image]

And for fun (and since I did it first), this version will only print `err` if an error is in the code.

#### x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>47</del> <del>45</del> 44 bytes

Binary:

```
00000000: bf80 00ba 1c01 8a0d 4951 abb8 6809 f3ae  ........IQ..h...
00000010: 5974 04b2 28b1 01cd 21e2 fcc3 4865 6c6c  Yt..(...!...Hell
00000020: 6f20 576f 726c 6424 6572 7224            o World$err$
```

Listing:

```
BF 0080         MOV  DI, 80H            ; DI to DOS PSP 
BA 011C         MOV  DX, OFFSET HW      ; point to 'Hello World' string 
8A 0D           MOV  CL, BYTE PTR[DI]   ; CL = input length 
49              DEC  CX                 ; remove leading space from length 
51              PUSH CX                 ; save length for later 
AB              STOSW                   ; DI to start of command line input
B8 0968         MOV  AX, 0968H          ; AL = 'h', AH = 9 
F3/ AE          REPZ SCASB              ; search input for 'h': ZF if Hello, NZ if error
59              POP  CX                 ; restore input length 
74 04           JZ   HELLO_LOOP         ; if no error, write Hello(s) 
B2 28           MOV  DL, LOW OFFSET ER  ; otherwise, point to 'err' string 
B1 01           MOV  CL, 1              ; only show 'err' once 
            WRITE_LOOP: 
CD 21           INT  21H                ; write string to stdout 
E2 FC           LOOP WRITE_LOOP         ; loop until done 
C3              RET                     ; return to DOS 
            HW  DB  'Hello World$'
            ER  DB  'err$'
```

[image]

Props:

- -1 byte for both thanks to @MatteoItalia for suggestion to change only the low byte on the error string pointer.

Comment: If you want to play dirty, you can shave 1 byte off from the second listing by changing `MOV  DX, OFFSET ER` to `MOV  DL, 2AH`.

Comment: A similar trick can be done in the first one, maybe moving the first `mov` over `dx` inside the loop just for good measure (I don't remember if dx is affected by the DOS call).

Comment: @MatteoItalia that is dirty! Though perhaps using a preprocessor operator like `LOW` would make it more clean. Don't see any reason it wouldn't work for the `ER` one. Great idea!

Comment: Didn't know about `LOW`, definitely better than hardcoding `A2H` :-D What assembler is this?

Comment: @MatteoItalia that's MASM syntax. Other assemblers may have their own similar way of doing the same I'd suspect.

Comment: Yep, I just tried with NASM (where labels are always evaluated to their addresses), and `mov dl, ER` already does "the right thing".

Comment: @MatteoItalia I tried just a `mov dl, offset ER` with MASM but it gives as `Value out of range` error.  Interestingly it will "correct" a `mov ax, bl` to `mov ax, bx` though, with a warning.

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-0p`, <sup><s>42...35</s></sup> 33 bytes

*The idea to use the `-0p` flags (instead of `-n` like I originally had) came from [@DomHastings's Perl answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210509/92901), saving 4 bytes.*

```ruby
$_=/[^h]/?:err:'Hello World'*~/$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/XyXeVj86LiNW394qtajISt0jNScnXyE8vygnRV2rTl9F////jIyMf/kFJZn5ecX/dQ0KAA)

Reads the program from STDIN. A regex is used to check whether the program contains any character other than `h`. If so, print `err`; otherwise, print `Hello World` as many times as the number of characters in the program (given by `~/$/`).

Using a bare regex literal as a boolean is a deprecated Perlism that (since Ruby 1.9) only works with the `-n` or `-p` flags.

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Good job! However, I noticed that an empty program [does not print err](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/PzEpv6hEPbWoSD0zrU4/Oi4jVt9axc7GRt0jNScnXyE8vygnRV2rTl9F////f/kFJZn5ecX/dfMA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: Sorry, was I unclear? By "empty", I mean a program that contains zero bytes.

Comment: @the-cobalt You're right. But your example Python code [behaves the same way](https://tio.run/##RYqxCoNAEAV7v@K5jVqnC1gG7C1SH2TFheNWnlfErz9PU2S6GWY78urpUYphhEizOBFgCfZsULGlajuiW7tfuGCwXTEfKYfvi3T2oqQM96Bx1/@60VLuZdIYHW9n/MhQygk).

Comment: @the-cobalt The empty program does not contain a non-h instruction, therefore it only contains `h`s, whether it actually has a `h` in it or not

Comment: Whoops, you're right! Let me reclarify the specs.

Comment: Hey, what does the `0` flag do in Ruby?! Though, it ran without it too, but I have never seen `0` in flags!!

Comment: @vrintle The `-0` flag sets the input record separator (newline by default). If no extra digits are given (as in this case) the separator becomes the null byte. This makes the code behave differently for an input of `h\nh` for example. Without `-0` you get the wrong output because Ruby sees the input as two lines. But with `-0`, `\n` isn't the line separator any more so the input is seen as a single line.

Answer (score 6):

## Excel, 63 bytes

```
=IF(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"h","")="",REPT("Hello World",LEN(A1)),"err")
```

---

`SUBSTITUTE(A1,"h","")=""` returns `TRUE` iff `A1` contains nothing but `h`.

`REPT("Hello World",LEN(A1))` repeats the string for however many characters are in `A1`.

`=If(Substitute(~)="",REPT(~),"err")` returns the repeated string if `A1` contains only `h` and `err` if it contains anything else.

Comment: I think the question spec calls for `Hello World` with an uppercase `W`

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing So it does, thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

<sup>14 if we can print `Err` as a substring of the output (e.g. `“½,⁾ẇṭ»€!fƑ?”h` [TIO](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//4oCcwr0s4oG@4bqH4bmtwrvigqwhZsaRP@KAnWj///9oaHhoaA)).</sup>

```
“½,⁾ẇṭ»€“¹ṫ»fƑ?”h
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDe3UeNe57uKv94c61h3Y/aloDEtv5cOfqQ7vTjk20f9QwN@P///8ZGRUZGQA)**

#### How?

```
“½,⁾ẇṭ»€“¹ṫ»fƑ?”h - Main Link: program
               ”h - set right argument to 'h'
              ?   - if...
             Ƒ    - ...condition: is (program) invariant under?:
            f     -     keep only ('h's)
       €          - ...then: for each (c in program):
“½,⁾ẇṭ»           -     "Hello World"
        “¹ṫ»      - ...else: "error"
                  - implicit, smashing print
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
'hÃQig”Ÿ™‚ï”×ë'‰ë
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPeNwc2Bm@qOGuUd3PGpZ9Khh1uH1QM7h6YdXqz9q2HB49f//SkpKGVwZGUAKAA)

Big thanks to @Kevin for your [dictionary compression tool](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/78850)!

And once again, Kevin has struck and managed to shave 3 bytes from my answer! So the aforementioned thanks is to be multiplied by a massive magnitude.

### Explained (old)

```
Ð'hÃQig”Ÿ™‚ï”и»ë"err
Ð                       # Triplicate the input. STACK = [input, input, input]
 'h                     # Push the letter 'h'. STACK = [input, input, input, 'h']
   Ã                    # Keep _only_ the letter h in the input. STACK = [input, input, input.keep('h')]
    Q                   # Compare this with the original input. STACK = [input, 1 OR 0]
     i                  # If the comparison is truthy (i.e. it's only h's):
      g                 #   Push the length of the input. STACK = [len(input)]
       ”Ÿ™‚ï”           #   Push the compressed string "Hello World". STACK = [len(input), "Hello World"]
             и»         #   Repeat that string length of input times and join upon newlines. STACK = ["\n".join("Hello World" * len(input))]
               ë        # Else:
                "err    #   Push the string "err" to the stack. STACK = [input, "err"]
                        # Implicitly output the top of the stack
```

Comment: [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8AT1jMPNgZnpjxrmHt3xqGXRo4ZZh9cDORd2HNp9eDWQ8ahhw@HV//8DAA) by printing `Error` instead of `err`. But there's a bug with both versions: they're supposed to error when the program contains a newline.

Comment: @Dingus You can have multi-line input by wrapping the input in `"""..."""`. And 2 more bytes can be saved. One by removing `Ð`, since the input is used implicitly anyway. And the other is by changing `и»` to `×` since without separator is allowed as well. PS: I had `Ù'hQ` instead of `'hÃQ`, but I like your approach more. :) [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPeNwc2Bm@qOGuUd3PGpZ9Khh1uH1QM7h6YdXqz9q2HB49f//ShlcGRlKAA)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks - I didn't know about the quotes for multi-line input. All credit for the approach goes to Lyxal of course.

Comment: Ah, I see I screwed up the input in the 17-byter I've linked, lol.. [Here the correct one.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPeNwc2Bm@qOGuUd3PGpZ9Khh1uH1QM7h6YdXqz9q2HB49f//SkpKGVwZGUAKAA)

Comment: Here also an [alternative 17-byter](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPcP7SEOm@qOGDYdXH159aM2jhrlHdzxqWfSoYdbh9UCO1f//SkpKGRkZQBIA) by porting the Japt approach, which could be [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPcP7SEOm@qOGDYdXH159buujhrlHdzxqWfSoYdbh9f//KykpZWRkAEkA) if outputting as a list of "Hello World" is allowed (which is an open question in the comments of the challenge).

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell (Hugs 2006), 31 bytes

```
mapM(\'h'->putStr"Hello World")
```

Pending a question to the OP r.e. "error" in a larger error message.
The spec says "it must print err or error", which it does on Hugs 2006, specifically the `Raskell 1.0.13 interpreter based on Hugs 2006`:

```
> mapM(\'h'->putStr"Hello World") "huh"
Hello World
Program error: pattern match
failure: ww_v4136 'u'
```

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript <s>72</s> 66 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to @Ismael Miguel

```
alert(/^h*$/.test(a=prompt())?a.replace(/h/g,'Hello World'):'err')
```

Comment: input is required, unless you're submitting as a function. Some rare questions allow input as variables, but that is not applicable here. Please do check https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods from more details.

Comment: If you want to save 1 byte, you can store `/h/g` into a variable. The final result would be like: `a=prompt();alert(a.replace(r=/h/g,'')?'err':a.replace(r,'Hello World'))`. If you are willing to take a different approach, you can test if `a` matches `/^h+$/` and then do the replacement as you have. It would look like this (66 bytes): `alert(/^h+$/.test(a=prompt())?a.replace(/h/g,'Hello World'):'err')`. I know it can be reduced, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcHBCoAgDADQX@kQqEF2D6Jrf9AtHDVQWU7m6PftvQwftFtS1bnwg70DoahdrjiNi1dsamGrwm9V69wOvlVKGmLwmVMJBxLxcLLQE1aDIsb1/gM) or [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1k4/LkNLRV@vJLW4RKNY0z5Rr7ggJ7MkISNBLys/My/BIzUnJ18hPL8oJyXBSj21qEj9/38A) as a function.

Comment: @Shaggy I've detected a possible bug on your version, and on the posted version. Your regex is `/^h*$/`, while the regex I've used is `/^h+$/`. The `+` is important if you want to make sure that there is at least an `h`, while `/^h*$/` will move on even on an empty input, which may be an undesirable behaviour, as an empty program seems to be invalid. (However, the implementation provided by O.P. simply outputs nothing for an empty program)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, we don't need to handle the empty input. You could also use `/[^h]/ ` for the same byte count and reverse the ternary.

Comment: @Shaggy That would probably be a more sane solution. And looks better, honestly. And is easier to explain and understand as well, for others that aren't familiar with the concept of regular expressions.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>71</s> 65 bytes

```c
f(char*p){p=*p-'h'?*p&&puts("err"):f(p+1)||!puts("Hello World");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7NDoIwEITvfYq1RmlRTLyK4tUHMPHiASg/bVKgacsJeHYskKjsaWd28s2yoGRsHAvCeKJ9RTt181Xgce/uq/1etdYQnGuN6aUg6nCmfb9ZzEcuZQOvRssM03AYn7mxQGDGgNJNqZMKaIfcLmpbAMFRFO9M/K7x8XcPERRkJRe6Q6IBoa2omWyzHK7GZqI58Qg5GFSJqAkFB19aMZ/yXzHNv6HbNBVmnZm@n0vGDw)

- Thanks to @rtpax for saving 6!

`f(char*p){p=`  - function tacking a `program` and returning with the eax trick, reusing `p`.
Calls itself recursively.
Recursion happens before `program` execution so if all steps are correct a `false` value is returned and the `program` is executed.
If there's an error a `truthy` value is returned and `program` is not executed at all, an error message is displayed.

```
*p-'h'? `...` :f(p+1)||!puts("Hello World");
 - check each character in program : if h  continue recursion and
   if result is false program do its job.
p is true  if there was an error, false instead.

 - if not h stop recursion and :
*p            - if end of program 
p  is false
&&puts("err") - if not end of program display error
p  is true.
```

---

[<s>61</s> 58 bytes](https://tio.run/##VU9BDoIwELz3FZs1YotiYuJJTL36ABMvHoBCoUmBpoUT4e0VMFHZ08zs7ExWRKUQ3ksqqtSGhg2hCQLTd46GJtpVuxsW1uIF74XWLTxbq3Nk/BwEkpr9icWjfxSuAwrLPRjbljatgQ1kwqrpJFDkPNm65NXg4bePCUi6oksp4gRHQjaqEbrPC7i6LlftseJkCoM6VQ1lMIV/WrGa/V8yz79g@yxTbu2Z/1hK/Bs) alternative less interesting solution which runs the program and stops when an error happens

```c
f(char*p){*p&&puts(*p-'h'?"err":"Hello World")>4&&f(p+1);}
```

- Saved 3 thanks to @rtpax !

Comment: I like it, but why is the 61-byte program less interesting?

Comment: @Dominic Van Essen thanks! In my opinion the 71 bytes exploits the combination of C's procedural with recursion(which feels more functional) to achieve a result where if there's any non `h` the program prints only an error. Nothing special.. just a recursion call before the function task and a global variable , [but I like it!](https://tio.run/##VY2xDoIwGIT3PsWfGmOLYHQVhdUHMHFxgJSWNgHatGUCnr1WGIz/dP9d7juWtYyFoHJBmKxtYuiUmJKoe2KygzzQ0ozeEcytxfQqiDleaKrmeXMfvOs0vLTtmpie8yU8ufNAYEWBsbq1dQ90QlGrwQsguCiqvaveA05/eY5AkL934@MoF4R2amDd2HC4Od8ofZIFijDoazUQChG@rWL5PdDGrb3wAQ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: Ah, I've got it: the 71-byter does extra work to *only* print 'err' for illegal input, but the 61-byter is lazy and prints some 'Hello World's if they come before the illegal letter.  It wasn't obvious (to me) without the test case with ```h```s before the illegal instruction.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: [66 bytes for the more interesting one](https://tio.run/##VU67DoIwFN37FdcaoUUxYRWF1Q8wcXEASgtNgDYtTIRvxwKJjzudV865LKwYm2dBWJ2bQNNR3wKdBjr0az/d6aG3BHNjML0Ioo8R9bxNu/OmUfBUpimdF8XT/OC2BwJrD2ijKpO3QEfksOx6AQQnSXaw2avDp68fIxDkj2792MEJob3sWDOUHK62L6U61wlyZdDmsiMUXPm2iusl/yHL/QpmKApp/zPL/@vI/AY "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @rtpax this is very interesting!

Comment: [58 bytes for the less interesting one](https://tio.run/##VU9BDoIwELz3FZs1YotiYuJJTL36ABMvHoBCoUmBpoUT4e0VMFHZ08zs7ExWRKUQ3ksqqtSGhg2hCQLTd46GJtpVuxsW1uIF74XWLTxbq3Nk/BwEkpr9icWjfxSuAwrLPRjbljatgQ1kwqrpJFDkPNm65NXg4bePCUi6oksp4gRHQjaqEbrPC7i6LlftseJkCoM6VQ1lMIV/WrGa/V8yz79g@yxTbu2Z/1hK/Bs "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [24 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
ùÝ└ån<⁼aLw$■v&Z(#▄╗└·I╔║
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=KCR7PSJoIn0pIz0jJiYneXQgYnMnXiN8fCJlcnI=&input=aApoaGhoaGgKcnViYmlzaA==)

## Explained

Unpacked: `(${="h"})#=#&&'yt bs'^#||"err`

And this is why I need to add an if else...

```
      (              Begin expression
        $            Filter
          {          Block with index of _
              _      Implicit
            =        Equals
              "h"    String
          }          End block
          _          Variable initialized to STDIN; implied
      )              End expression
    #                Length
  =                  Equals
      _              Implied
    #
&&                   Boolean AND
    'yt bs'        Compressed string equal to "Hello World"
  ^                  Repeated
      _              Implied
    #
||                   Boolean OR
  "err
```

Answer (score 4):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 94 bytes

```
	I =INPUT
	I NOTANY('h')	:S(E)
	OUTPUT =DUPL('Hello World',SIZE(I))	:(END)
E	OUTPUT ='err'
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NTwdbTLyA0hAvI8vMPcfSL1FDPUNfktArWcNXk4vQPDQFKKti6hAb4aKh7pObk5CuE5xflpKjrBHtGuWp4agKVarj6uWhyucIVq6cWFalzAQX///dwBQA)

```
	I =INPUT					;* Read input
	I NOTANY('h')	:S(E)				;* If there is a character that's not 'h' in the input, goto E
	OUTPUT =DUPL('Hello World',SIZE(I))	:(END)	;* else print "Hello World" repeatedly and goto END
E	OUTPUT ='err'					;* print 'err'
END
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 49 bytes

-4 bytes if we can *throw* an error instead of outputting a string.

```
f=([c,...a])=>c?c==`h`?`Hello World`+f(a):`err`:a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjOllHT08vMVbT1i7ZPtnWNiEjwT7BIzUnJ18hPL8oJyVBO00jUdMqIbWoKMEq8X9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahlKGkqYmF7oYCGAVr8Aq7gEU@w8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [flex](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/flex_1.html), <sup><s>76</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>55</s></sup> 52 bytes

```
%%
h puts("Hello World");
[^h] puts("err");exit(1);
```

Put the above code in a file called `hello.l` and make the interpreter with:

```
flex hello.l && gcc lex.yy.c -o hello -lfl
```

Trying it on my terminal:

```
> echo -n hhh|./hello.exe
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

With newline:

```
> echo hhh|./hello.exe
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
err
```

notice the `err` because of the trailing newline `echo` normally sends.

With non-`h` character:

```
> echo -n hhhehhh|./hello.exe
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
err
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 58 bytes

```python
lambda s:s and s=="h"*len(s)and"Hello World"*len(s)or"err"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcoxCsMwDEDR3acQnuwOWboVvPcGXbq4yCECRTaSOuT0Tlvo9nn8cfjW5TrX8pxc9xdWsJtBFQQrJW7xwk2S5Q/Ee2Pu8OjK@OeusanGSfvo6mCHBZLxdijfXsyRZNFWkUlaCENJPK3p96Sc8zwB)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 52 bytes

```python
lambda x:(x=='h'*len(x))*len(x)*'Hello World'or'err'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcYxDsMgDEDRvafwZjtDlm6V2HuDLFmoIALJwcgwkNOTDP3L@/XqSct7HuBgn@LPX/AwPjScw4SLxEKD@e@C3yiisKlJQDWMZjjzWdU6tKu9quXS6aDn19ZDLqtFH4iZZ3q6AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>57</s> 52 bytes

```python
lambda a:a=='h'*len(a)and'Hello World'*len(a)or'err'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VckxDoMwDEDRnVN4c8LKVik7N@jSxVWCHGFs5EZCPX3KgirG9//@bWw69SW9utD2zgT0oJSQcZSigSJpxrmIGDzNJV/ZHIs79t2rtrAEZGaMcfj7psb1A0cVAbUGh/l67v4D)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
aRM'h?"err""Hello World"X#a
```

-1 byte from DLosc.

If the string without h's is empty, print "Hello World" required number of times.

Otherwise, error.

This program errors on empty input as well.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/MchXPcNeKbWoSEnJIzUnJ18hPL8oJ0UpQjnx////GRCQAwA)

Comment: Yep, almost exactly my solution. One trick to save a byte: you can use `M` with a scalar lhs to do the equivalent of `[scalar for i in iterable]` in Python. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/NDAxUD3DXskjNScnXyE8vygnRck3USm1qEjp////GRkZAA)

Comment: Oh, actually, here's another byte: Test `aRM'h` and switch the true and false branches.

Comment: Just read the docs. Empty string is falsy, eh?

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <sup><s>23</s></sup> 19 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

-4 bytes thanks to @Shaggy

```
rh ?`r`:¡`HÁM Wld
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=cmggP2CAcmA6oWBIwU0gV45sZA&input=Imgi)

### Explanation

```
rh ?`...`:¡`...
   ?              // if
rh                //   input with 'h' removed
    `...`         // then "err"
         :        // else
          ¡       //   each char in input
           `...   //   replaced with "Hello World"
```

Comment: [19 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=cmggP2CAcmA6oWBIwU0gV45sZA&input=Imgi)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), <s><sup>48</sup></s> 47 bytes

*Thanks to @DLosc for -1 bytes*

```
:g/\_$\_^\|[^h]/norm HcGerr
:s/h/Hello World/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/3ypdPyZeJSY@LqYmOi4jVj8vvyhXwSPFPTO1qIjLqlg/Q98jNScnXyE8vygnRT@d6///DBQAAA)

The `:g` command is a bit convoluted, but there's a reason for that. The `[^h]` part will match all non-`h` characters, but it won't match newlines. `$` or `\n` will match end-of-line, which means they will match a single line without a newline. To make it match only when there are multiple lines, I used `\_$\_^`. This will only match newlines (`\_$`) that are followed by another line (`\_^`).

For some reason, this doesn't work properly in TIO, so programs where the only non-`h` characters are newlines won't error. However, this does work properly in Vim.

Explanation:

```
:g/    (x)     /     (y)     # If x exists, execute y:
   \_$\_^                    #  x -> An end-of-line followed by a start-of-line;
         \|[^h]              #   OR any character that isn't 'h'
                norm HcGerr  #  y -> Delete all lines, then print 'err'

:s/h/Hello World/g           # Replace every 'h' with 'Hello World'
```

Comment: I think `HdGi` can become `HcG` for -1 byte.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>65</s> 53 bytes

```java
s->s.matches("h+")?s.replace("h","Hello World"):"err"
```

-12 bytes thanks to *@corvus_192*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fZC/TsMwEMb3PsXplsYKzQOkAgYWOrQMDAyUwXHcxsVxIt@5CFV59uAEZwRL/nNnf7/7zhd5lZtL/TkqK4lgL427rQCMY@1PUmk4TCHAK3vjzqCydCCxjflhFRdiyUbBARzcw0ibBypayarRlGGTo3ikwuveRliM8Q6ftbUdvHXe1ihK1N7juJ1AfahsBCXetTM1tNFPKvn@AVL8mjl1fvHBmvhJkoYSnP6C5eltrtTEETcfqsrQnDi6Zpo4JFJs7JtYt0UXuOijlq3LcOf6wCUcEfOFn69xPbf8l@Yl8CzC3BUqW2TiP026G@aPHMYf)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->                           // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  s.matches("h+")?            //  If the input consists solely of 1 or more "h":
    s.replace("h",            //   Replace all "h" in the input
              "Hello World")  //   with "Hello World"
             :                //  Else:
              "err"           //   Return "err" instead
```

Comment: There must be a fancy way to raise an exception here.

Comment: @Razetime Probably, but the challenge states to output `"err"` or `"error"`, not to cause an error/exception.

Comment: I think you can use `s.matches("h*")` instead

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>23</s> 20 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
'h-╛æ╖•p0{δ╕○ô 'W╕7ÿ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/189Q/fR1NmHlz2aOu1Rw6ICg@pzWx5NnfpoevfhLQrq4UCm@eH9//8rZShxKWVkQMiYvAwwAeQUlSYlZRZnKAEA)

**Explanation:**

```python
'h-                  '# Remove all "h" from the (implicit) input-string
   ╛                  # Pop, and if it's now truthy (thus non-empty):
    æ                 #  Use the following four characters as single code-block:
     ╖•p              #   Push compressed string "err"
        0             #   And push a 0
         {            # Either loop 0 times,
                      # or loop over each character of the (implicit) input-string:
          δ           #  Titlecase the implicitly pushed current character ("h"→"H")
           ╕○ô        #  Push compressed string "ello"
                      #  Push " "
               'W    '#  Push "W"
                 ╕7ÿ  #  Push compressed string "orld"
                      # (implicitly output the entire stack joined together as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## SimpleTemplate 0.84, <del>92</del> 63 bytes

This challenge was simple, yet fun!

Simply checks if the input is just "hhh...." and outputs the text, or outputs "err" to STDOUT:

```
{@ifargv.0 matches"@^h+$@"M}{@eachM.0}Hello World{@/}{@else}err
```

The big byte saving was due to [the-cobalt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97771/the-cobalt)'s comment:

> Outputting to STDOUT is fine, so you could use your 63 byte version.

---

**Ungolfed:**

Below is a more readable version of the code:

```
{@if argv.0 matches "@^h+$@"}
    {@each argv.0 as h}
        {@echo "Hello World"}
    {@/}
{@else}
    {@echo "err"}
{@/}
```

---

You can try this on: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e35a07dfbf6b3b56c2608aa86028b395ef457129

Comment: Outputting to STDOUT is fine, so you could use your 63 byte version.

Comment: @the-cobalt Thank you for confirming that, I've implemented it.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 44 bytes

```powershell
$args|%{if($_-104){'err';exit}"Hello World"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V8lsSi9uEa1OjNNQyVe19DARLNaPbWoSN06tSKzpFbJA6gwXyE8vygnRan2fy0Xl3oGCKjrKIGMyFcC0iAApIvzSwuUgAYphRRVZualK6jEK1gpWauppCk4xFurq9f@BwA)

Takes input by splatting

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge-93, <strike>58</strike> 56 bytes

```
~:1+!#v_"h"-#v_"dlroW olleH",,,,,,,,,,,  
  @,,,@#"err"<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/v87KUFtRuSxeKUNJF0Sl5BTlhyvk5@SkeijpIICCApeCggOQ4aCslFpUpGTz/39GRgYA)

### How does it work?

```
~                         # Read a character.

:1+!                      # Check whether we read -1 (end of input);
                          # this leaves 1 on the stack if we are at 
                          # the end of the input, else 0.

#v_                       # Exit the program if we're at the end
 @                        # end of the input.

"h"-                      # Compare the read character with the
                          # character "h", if equal, we leave 0 on
                          # the stack, otherwise, non-zero.

          #v_             # If we read anything but "h", print "err"
@,,,@#"err"<              # and exit the program.

"dlroW olleH",,,,,,,,,,,  # Print "Hello World"
```

Comment: You can print it all out at the end for [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/v87KUFtRuSxeKUNJF0Sl5BTlhyvk5@SkeigpKHApKNhZKevEOyiAgJ2BUlFRqtL//xkZGQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 63 bytes

```
method(:,:foreach(X,if(X!=104,"err"print-,"Hello World"print)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcm9CoAgFEDh3aewOykYFDQJ7b1BDi39KArmjZs9v4Wd8XwBi@N65Es5bfZ4CK20Q7Lr7oVRwQnTjH03KLBEcFFIuVUw2RiRz0jx@J@UsjgBvgaSMQBeISbGPqBn28L9SXkB)

### Explanation

```
method(i,                         // Take input
    i foreach(X,                  // For every item:
        if(X!=104,                //     If the codepoint isn't 104:
             "err"print           //         print "err" (w/o nl)
                       -          //         Subtract "err" by the "Object" class (causes error)
             ,"Hello World"print  //     Otherwise, print "Hello World" (w/o nl)
)))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>84</s> 80 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat). It's beautiful!

```c
main(c,v)char**v;{*v[1]++-'h'?*--v[1]&&puts("err"):main(puts("Hello World"),v);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1mnTDM5I7FIS6vMulqrLNowVltbVz1D3V5LVxfEU1MrKC0p1lBKLSpS0rQCa4EIeKTm5OQrhOcX5aQoaQINsa79//9/RkZGIgA)

Not so fancy, but I like that it's a complete program **`:)`**

"Normal" version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (*argv[1]++ - 'h')
        return *--argv[1] && puts("err");
    else
        return main(puts("Hello World"), argv);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

GFA Basic (Atari ST), 125 bytes

```
INPUT a$
FOR i=1 TO LEN(a$)
b$=MID$(a$,i,1)
IF b$="h"
PRINT "Hello World"
ELSE
PRINT "err"
EXIT IF 1
ENDIF
NEXT I
```

Comment: Can the if statement be shortened to `PRINT ... IF b$="h" ELSE PRINT  ...`?

Comment: @Razetime I don't know any version of GFA Basic that would allow this syntax.

Comment: You can do `IF b$<>"h" / PRINT "err" / EXIT IF 1 / ENDIF / PRINT "Hello World"` to get rid of the `ELSE`.

Comment: See for instance [this answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204733/58563) for some tricks to reduce the byte count (using abbreviated keywords and ending each line with `CR` instead of `CRLF`).

Answer (score 2):

### K, 38 bytes

```
{$[&/"h"=x;,/{"Hello World"}'x;"err"]}
```

- `{..x..}` defines a function with implicit arg x.
- `$[cond; a; b]` corresponds to a "if (cond) {a} else {b}" sentence
- The condition  `&/"h"=x` can be read as "((string x).map(char is "h").reduce(and))"
- `,/{..}'x`defines a function that applies to each char of x, and catenates results.
- `{"Hello World"}` is a function without args that returns string "Hello World"
  `

#### Examples

- `{$[&/"h"=x;,/{"Hello World"}'x;"err"]}"hhhh"`

`"Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World`

- `{$[&/"h"=x;,/{"Hello World"}'x;"err"]}"hhxh"`

`"err"`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-0pF`, 30 bytes

Thanks to Abigail for helping let me know about a bug and providing a solution.

```perl
$_=/[^h]/?err:"Hello World"x@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lY/Oi4jVt8@tajISskjNScnXyE8vygnRanCwe3//wyuf/kFJZn5ecX/dQ0K3AA)

Comment: This one prints "Hello World" on an input of "h\n" -- it's not clear from the description whether that's allowed. You can fix that without loss of bytes by using `/[^h]/` as the pattern, and swapping the cases in `?:`. [Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lY/Oi4jVt8@tajISskjNScnXyE8vygnRanCwe3//wyuf/kFJZn5ecX/dQ0K3AA)

Comment: Thank you @Abigail!

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 25 bytes

```
?-Q\h"err"*"Hello World"l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3143MCZDKbWoSElLySM1JydfITy/KCdFKef/f6WMjEIlAA)

### Explanation

```
?-Q\h"err"*"Hello World"l
?                           // if
 -Q\h                       //    input with 'h' removed
     "err"                  // then "err"
          *"Hello World"l   // else "Hello World" repeated len(input) times
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 84 bytes

```r
function(p,n=nchar(p))`if`(n-lengths(gregexpr("h",p)),"err",strrep("Hello World",n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxNCoMwEIX3PYXMagbSI7jvDdxa7ZgEwiS8ROjtU7WUvtX740MPmlIe@7bb2mI2Ls5GW8MTXETmuM1s96TmW6jsoV7fBUyB3DE7UoBcbYAWpseJGqaM9CJnIl/2eZbbz176Z@zLEutR9A8)

As [R](https://www.r-project.org/) is the [Language of the month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19304/language-of-the-month-for-september-2020-r) for September 2020, let's get the ball rolling with an R answer to this challenge.
However, this is still not the shortest-possible answer in [R](https://www.r-project.org/), so I'd like to encourage other not-normally-R-golfers to have a go, too...

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 64 bytes

```
@set/ps=
@if "%s:h=%"=="" (echo %s:h=Hello World%)else echo err
```

Takes input on STDIN. If replacing the `h`s in the input results in an empty string, output the result of replacing the `h`s with `Hello World` otherwise output `err`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
¿⁻θh¦err⭆θHello World
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8zTUHDNzOvtFijUEdBKUNJU1MhoCgzr0RDKbWoSEnTWiE1pzgVKhRcAqTSfRMLwGo9UnNy8hXC84tyUoDq/v/PyMj4r1uWAwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
¿⁻θh
```

Delete all `h`s from the implicit input.

```
err
```

If the result is empty then output `err`.

```
Ｆθ
```

Otherwise the input only contains `h`s. Loop over each `h`.

```
Hello World
```

Output `Hello World` for each one.

Other options for the same byte count:

```
¿⁻θh¦err⭆θHello World
```

Replaces each `h` with `Hello World` and prints the result.

```
¿⁻θh¦errＥθHello World
```

Prints each `Hello World` on its own line.

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 65 bytes

```
func[s][either"h"= unique s[replace/all s"h""Hello World"]['err]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYqxDoMwDAV3vsLy0pG9EnvnLh0sD0BelEhWAId8f0Bd2jed7p4j9DeC6BCfPbaySlVBPhOcE0/USj4aqIpjt3nFOJtRvRO/YLbRZ3MLrPKAu2rfPZeTIt2H4cff/Qlvy5Jr4n4B)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 44 bytes

```
i:0(?;"dlroW olleH"oooooooo!;ooo"errh"{=?!|]
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9PKQMPeWiklpyg/XCE/JyfVQykfChStgYRSalFRhlK1rb1iTez//xkZGaWlAA)

Always fun when one can golf by reusing some of the code by running it backwards.

```
i:0(?;"rre'oodlroW olleH"o83*0l9)?.{"h"=?!']
```

Alternatively, for the same byte count, one can exploit the fact that "dlroW", "World" backwards, can be used to print an additional character and terminate.

Comment: I don't think printing Hello World before checking the character is allowed. The input `huh` should print one Hello World before printing err, not two. Also, if you could include a link to [TIO](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9PKQMPeWiklpyg/XCE/JyfVQykfChStgYRSalFRhlK1rb1iTez//xmlGQA) for testing, that would be nice

Comment: @JoKing I figured it was allowed since "It's okay if you print "Hello World"s before your program discovers a non-h character and errors" doesn't specify the number, and we are allowed to assume the input is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 80 bytes

```lua
(...):gsub('.',load'print(...=="h"and"Hello World"or print("err")or os.exit())')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcrBCYAwDEDRVSSXNiAZQPDuBp4rLUYIjaQW3D4qHj/vS0/ukYhw2lvfYqAwiqYcTjvq9cE8A0OqGZYiosOqJhnUhn@AYgb4pjYq93FFxIDuzsydHw)

Not really fun...

Or, if 'err' can be a part of error message, like python example from question:

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 67 bytes

```lua
(...):gsub('.',load'print(...~="h"and ("err")() or "Hello World")')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FckxCoAwDADAr4QsaUD6AMHdHzhXWowQGol29esRbz0dJSLlnHk@7rEnyjSplUqXn/35411QsPQKCZs7cmIwB1ybqsFmrhWZOCJEhnw)

By calling "err", it will appear in error message.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 57 bytes

```
""<>If[Union@#=={"h"},"Hello World"~Table~Tr[1^#],"err"]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYyxCoMwFAB/JTzBKRC6NyXQpd06KB3Ewot9NYGYwDNOUn89td503HATZkcTZj9gGXUBOF/un66NPkVTab2Cg6@EG4WQxDNxeMPWoA20NdydXlUvgZihr8uDfcxCmVGZq0PGIRPPygjxX0hwB7vwYq2fj7Ts71J@)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 66 bytes

```forth
: f bounds do i c@ 'h - if ." err"leave then ." Hello World"loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PUy7CgIxEOz9imGbq2Jh6YFY@gfW5rIxgXAbNong18fLITfNPBkvWoN5@0G9X@Fhpa2uwAkiljumAIPocSawKiV@fRg18DqSB6ckeIomR0kkY94uMi6uZdRv5rGBuYG230UxnwohEPLOO/5Gm7WxHFUbqv8A)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f                 \ start a new word definition
  bounds            \ get starting and ending address for string
  do                \ loop from starting char address to ending char address
    i c@            \ get character at current address
    'h -            \ check if not equal to "h" (save a byte by using - instead of <>)
    if              \ if character is not h
      ." err"leave  \ print "err" and exit the loop
    then            \ end if
    ." Hello World" \ print "Hello World"
  loop              \ end the loop
;                   \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 100 bytes

```
> InputAll
> "Hello World"
> "h"
> "err"
>> 1∖3
>> Output 4
>> #1
>> 2⋅7
>> Output 8
>> If 5 6 9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsEzr6C0xDEnh8tOQckjNScnXyE8vygnRQnEzwCTqUVFQNpOwfBRxzRjEMO/tASoR8EExFY2BJFGj7pbzZGkLEBszzQFUwUzBcv//zPAAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 20 bytes

```
?*¨H◄⁰ω]!¨L¹¨Ėr¨Λ='h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/317r0AqPR9NbHjVuON8Zq3hohc@hnYdWHJlWdGjFudm26hn////PAIMiAA)

An if statement with compressed strings using [This utility](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzlFQT@/oEQ/o7Q4m6uoNC8jsTg7NSdHITk/t6Aotbg4uKQoMy9dL6NYQSm1qEjp/38A)

Comment: [Alternative 20 byter](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9odXNr//8/byrCqEjil4TigbDPiV0hwqjihpDCqMSWcsKozps9J2j///9oaHI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes, Courtesy of Lyxal

```
\hJ≈[\h↔Lkh*|«∧↳
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5ChJ%E2%89%88%5B%5Ch%E2%86%94Lkh*%7C%C2%AB%E2%88%A7%E2%86%B3&inputs=hhh&header=&footer=)

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 32 bytes

```
\hṡ¤=≈['\h=;L`Hello World`*|`err
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5Ch%E1%B9%A1%C2%A4%3D%E2%89%88%5B%27%5Ch%3D%3BL%60Hello%20World%60*%7C%60err&inputs=hh&header=&footer=)

Comment: [21 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5Ch%E1%B9%A1%C2%A4%3D%E2%89%88%5B'%5Ch%3D%3BLkh*%7C%60err&inputs=hh&header=&footer=)

Comment: [actually, 17 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5ChJ%E2%89%88%5B%5Ch%E2%86%94Lkh*%7C%60err&inputs=hhh&header=&footer=)

Comment: [okay last one: 16 bytes (btw that beats my 05ab1e answer, which I'm very happy about)](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5ChJ%E2%89%88%5B%5Ch%E2%86%94Lkh*%7C%C2%AB%E2%88%A7%E2%86%B3&inputs=hhh&header=&footer=)

Comment: @lyxal so many thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I'm very happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc) - 99 bytes, input using `stdin`

```c
i;main(){char x[99];gets(x);for(;x[i];++i){if(x[i]-'h'){puts("err");break;}puts("Hello World");}}
```

(Like I said in my last answer to some other question) This program can only handle `99` characters, and uses the unsafe `gets()` function.

An alternative, also 99 bytes:

```c
i;main(){char x[99];gets(x);for(;x[i];++i){if(x[i]-104){puts("err");break;}puts("Hello World");}}
```

Comment: [88 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOjcxM09Dszo5I7FIoSLa0jLWOi2/SCM9taRYo0LTuiI6M1ZNTVEDROuqZ6irqRWUAmWUUouKlDQ1rbW1MzUhAh6pOTn5CuH5RTkpSprWtf//Z5RmAAA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 67 [bits<sup>v1</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 8.375 bytes

```
ƛ\h=[kH|«½F
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJBaj0iLCIiLCLGm1xcaD1ba0h8wqvCvUYiLCIiLCJoaGhoYVxuaGhoaFxuaFxucnViYmlzaFxuaHVoIl0=)

```
ƛ           # map the following over the input
 \h=[       # if it is equal to `h`
     kH     # push `Hello World`
       |    # else
        «½F # push the compressed string `err`
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++, <s>192</s> 121 bytes

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    char a;
    while (true) {
        std::cout << ">> ";
        std::cin >> a;
        if (a != 'h') {
            std::cout << "err";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "hello world\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
Shrunken to 121 bytes

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){char a;while(1){std::cin>>a;if(a!='h'){std::cout<<"err";}else{std::cout<<"hello world";}}}
```

Comment: Welcome to CG&CC! We require submissions to make some effort to be competitive; try removing unnecessary whitespace, then consider checking out our [tips for golfing in C++](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132/tips-for-golfing-in-c). Also consider including a link to an online interpreter, like TIO. Happy golfing!

Comment: [94 bytes](https://tio.run/##JccxDoQgEADA3lcQrhAKPwCEe8tmQdkEWbNiLIxv54qbbvA4lg1xjA81rFfKgfjskmGPE7WudqBm7LOyGCwgCvzZk3NILUbw9h@@eggGlrnMX51FtNMl18rqZqlJW/@OUX4 "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62pCgzV0Ml0VYlsSi9LNowVkc9Q11T0VZd3V49tahI3aq4pCi@KLUgNbFEQ90jNScnXyE8vygnRV0HKJGTmgfUqqlp/f///4yMDAA), 72 bytes

```
<?=trim($a=$argv[1],'h')!=''?'err':str_repeat('Hello World',strlen($a));
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Dart](https://dart.dev/), 83 bytes

```
void h(p)=>print(p.contains(RegExp("[^h]"))?"err":p.replaceAll("h","Hello World"));
```

My first try on Dart although I'm not completely familiar with it. Maybe the call of the method can be shortend.

Explanation: simply check with a Regular Expression if there is something else than `h` in the input. If so print `err`, else replace all the `h` with `Hello World`.

[Try it online!](https://dartpad.dev/7d78af42d7b0aedfd92f00899f93561b)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript ES6, 51 chars

```
s=>s.replace(/h|.+/g,m=>m=='h'?"Hello World":"err")
```

Runnable example:

```js
f=s=>s.replace(/(h)|.+/g,(m,h)=>h?"Hello World":"err") // 52 chars
f=s=>s.replace(/h|.+/g,m=>m=='h'?"Hello World":"err")  // 51 chars
inp.addEventListener('input',e=>out.textContent=f(inp.value))
```

```css
input { width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<input id=inp autofocus>
<output id=out></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>84</s> 65 bytes

```
listen to S
cut S
while S
say roll S's "h" and "Hello World" or e
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 69 bytes

```
a=b=length($0){for(;b--;)x=x"Hello World"}$0=NR*gsub("h",c)-a?"err":x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v8/0TbJNic1L70kQ0PFQLM6Lb9IwzpJV9das8K2QskjNScnXyE8vygnRalWxcDWL0grvbg0SUMpQ0knWVM30V4ptahIyari//8MIAAA)

The command to get a string length is pretty long in AWK, so this

```
a=b=length($0)
```

saves the values in two variables for use later.  Since we're guaranteed some input, the test is always truthy and the code will execute.

```
{for(;b--;)x=x"Hello World"}
```

The body just appends copies of `Hello World` to `x`, one for each letter in the input.

```
$0=NR*gsub("h",c)-a?"err":x
```

Sets the default output `$0` to `err` or the string of concatenated `Hello World` strings.  The `gsub("h",c)-a` is truthy if number of `h` characters in the input matches the length of the string.  The `NR*` multiple will sabotage the comparison if this isn't the first input line.

Well then...  After reading some other entries, and specifically the one from jmizv I realized a simpler (and shorter) approach like this works.

```
NR*length($0)!=gsub("h","Hello World"){$0="err"}1
```

But that's a completely different program, so I'm going to leave the original one in place.

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 54 bytes

```
BEGIN{RS="^$"}/[^h]/{$0="err"}1gsub(/h/,"Hello World")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686KNhWKU5FqVY/Oi4jVr9axcBWKbWoSKnWML24NElDP0NfR8kjNScnXyE8vygnRUnz//@MjAwA)

```
BEGIN{RS="^$"}
```

We begin setting the Record Separator as `"^$"`, which makes AWK read the input as a whole.

```
/[^h]/{$0="err"}
```

If there is anything different from `h`, the whole input is substituted by the `"err"` string.

```
1gsub(/h/,"Hello World")
```

This is the number `1` and the result of `gsub(/h/,"Hello World")` concatenated, which will be evaluated as an AWK pattern. `gsub` tries to find every `h`, and substitutes each one for a `Hello World`. If `$0` was changed for `err`, `gsub` returns `0`, hence the concatenation. Thus, It will always result true, printing `$0` (simply `err` or a bunch of `Hello World`).

Answer (score 0):

## [ErrLess](https://sr.ht/%7Eruan_p/ErrLess), 43 bytes

```
SSQl0=2+].0g'h=1-[{SHello WorldS?c]}SerrS?.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1Vvpdts2Fv6vp0Ank4q0tbqddkaJkqbZ6tMkTmPPVlnVoUhIYkIRLADFklP35zzAPOK8SOZeACTBRbKS1tOOz4kigsC9311xsSjZyAWLP2snm2Tz/hZ5QqW/oAGZcbYkCykTMeh256HsCN5ZyO7PfOXFk6RLOY@oEBNOZ6IrOaXdpRfG3VDSZXcazsNYTlZx6LOAdhPNIB3SSTbkK9L/krxgb8lR76jfaITLhHFJxEakX2W4pI2GH3lCkDBOBg0CfwGdkckkjEM5mTiCRjNXt@MfPnYCT3pkSJrNRtZ/TmUUxrTcnVO54rE16hC5d4QMwrjDqReoQe5o0O6PC8QUoRYR4SUdtvsWxXCmGsld0htcT95xcyiAOOs4GiCR8Z2CPPlbfDkYl6XgVfLYsR3R2OGuW8AfljUR0zmweOJFglYhocD9HOrFIowo4Z1QiMTzQT85mV3DJN8UO4KuoC8Yqt0cGABnfEXvbKWQM4@ZJHwEVslBEC8OsrYAfE@WgWlwh9tp29pWlFCjaVtFRq7dotCsLQFuDxpH@RAnSkZBr6St27MRdO3TRBLnb160oo85Z7xFjuOArtX3slY16RH4IUQCsIdPcJ8GGjRKWOJELRLmvgi8QxHGQnoxKAfeRaGQ7nlKEnXlOCG5NyQ99RCCx6KjRK5LGCcOPus3Tjt0yd1h@rYaPVEH2YdaLgumRkbpm98Q2igc18ISYHxE1SLr/yEqhAOWW1uQNJ5Z5Empumdg0HNqAGVJZRQZyYDgSH@dAQ4KfkEiSxEdugbKgZOyoG7BUFwD8FmysbnXcS4rd6QGUdfiW1B2pEkHbLJy0lSjhJ046yq1GTTWyL023HUEjWDsRjPcIMN1geFsknEMKhxbZGMx9VpkijFUZdSyGzem0U7vnjLytD46gdNli1xoiPgNUV6GieafJwsaIaVdNIyYl5aY2cDtzIHNpTVwM65RM9Iuq01PsS8oyD2N6CB1pwuPB6CmdxmV5iWk6ub3zVbe8g5bruwWB1tcu2WJLc9Ny5X6nHr@myr5DXb8pz30Clve2S0utjh2y3NsWWbklROIN2Ey8dlySSHpJpzNWySRkGCNVGKIU03q8LEPMPpo3fS1ydh99d5feBhmSGUERLRSY1CWSsO@ehSShzFOYdhZz7VmqoJ@ub1gOM5A6ai06bZOF8ghd7ZathavQ8PMck49ZKisUvARhRYG9IuelPW/quvfxv62qzgA4xCwu7cztC2DxtK60aGtdSQHnYaqwGgRSEjDFyxO9b9VvxPwR/8NZjjsMq5RtJGbYkYGBwaaA/UwzJy5Y@AYEiXLaA4V@/RvxDqOUQNOGKnmcxCj3lgXMeoVRG9Zgkr1tNXaBniLTLCSqo0EtzIgxz2pvPNZDMBXtOIjGnrHSxKcZBCQW/QwBzWX93TJJ7Z288m1LKyqzyzlQKnVUvZ1UWLFaLANDdYjJRhlFEOM90zZ8ATwr6FXCYT@7jBIM9zvJQ5SPPsHQvv3FgipCNsj4erDI6Gllz2/24BIhf6/jgi5SoDpB9eYOIw66eC1Lm3WqtbU4ihRipTUmJq1QE1typn0pBrEkutL73qK1QEsSYtWAIv6AOK4IOhvoSCXuJ7LlkoswQDIKvoQpeVePKdOv5WSs8BAPacJwGerQCUc5yZPVzyqGVc9jVJrb6zouDVamnNv6gigbakpbZ84WZMKmdTx0yUpYtUDcBmgRrg4xOh/pZ1lgL6ignGAi2d0HUxGSotQsq1iMSBB6ING2/ewgylQV3Eh76jGW7fI6dmDh9@Sk5ePXz04Oz55cdpI7aQGQJIYQL14izxksQ/Wj@Ffvi5QhgDoOiiy9umWdpXLitb3jPH1srD0cpq@LEZWIWeMoJM3tqNV0EGxy5QcEs8ti7VWYj1QXa6VKNou0bX@X4Uc1UAudI/Srp67nUxUEemOEumUJpTvY6YqeK8WPI4fefZMhSjMStmzMkuK4xOF4yVLcv2V2Be6f6W6P8K05du4ccGgl9oqTPVwt1GrDFlDd67oPoUoysawZKeBczbZCx3O2JaGdJXR04yR3gFW3a/naZM2/9WSjxT5ZzSey0Vhf7DkD7glYmuqsnd2tkn0zllpZLtfw/WZxZWwWUmoCmfbOgU6XNF5peaOok6yfZxcN1usm848eUcrVxa4vbK41dlhJ0/DZpctWoo@VhuNLbGdEx7XjP@jDtELL/noLFoIPwzZabpdDdn8WSgh@CPRKLKGSbHZ6x999vmfvvjyz3/xpj7MJ1qS1XJKuagXBndgYXSL9L@o0/V5U88MUAF5vrSppOvCO9vr4AIjZup@NTPVsTrVajt7dfziaaNQqYq0Uq1ZR5t1A4zewneEjH1dJ/moJDHq4za1lZzN5A70Mh0/4Bu5WHoy9BtVpId6WgmCX2hfg1DtzkXechp4WLtAzK8PNy7OjF6dntpaT6upRJPcGIT2DggTEyFzO97LBFcZwQFpr91CONbQPFA0n68iGSbR5sbEOtghVldPUuHbMPj4Akitdr0ZDcK35T3WLKcbh1t3u5vCS5PDv6ecIQoRstjkcjOit0NOw3S7eLe1hlmwitgvFm/JgmvFu/0rSwc8t0t3fp5aD7r9GtbbQ0K71weK2trHlrbAaWZ6yJaJx0PB4prMNFQ6ePzjyotCeWNB1O4fOOvhcONut8ZdU1kIQeTCi28Uyd1dQO6Zuo1CquI3j@WehSW12NehvAgFJV3yjM2h/I3IiarewSlEjQ1/1sn15GyvzPrz9Zn1Uz1dvXh0Y0n10x1J9SfF/eTVjTH/aQfzHxTzf9wg9x82FXufyAXlNYaVOiZCKSNKzm4KERZ064N@7@BgV1icKSxfh3Oyn5shVaS5dq91t8QW8@XNinm0W8qXmZQv95byqE7IPPnGkrOIPInYRY2FO4rfN14ky7WlOTcr9L5UvZ@k52tPmWSF6np70atO6ka9cV0FW2Gz0Uowe6bb@dTtzn8Qo3eK0dkFa194GzLfwqZ67rIv/ZEufIFIprRs3OvlthV4glsMxW142@qvAcMwkQOSdCYTQSVe1JpMHJifHdwCbL@2NnDBLV6nG4K5VIncV4BxLkBmjhuX4PAXSJC6/UvOfBqsOBXkU/Lc8zmrm7gcvSWU9i2u4YC9f90yLseFG5yjbIfcCsWx3t/09RpuL60vFSybcRHZ0vu1gDl45A7kNDh3L3R/0JsZ8JQprqs0nLPc4haqEEXoBUwz@06FrkK/pRtTfPopSMhUOaFl5Z5b8QTBr54gqAMf3Loble57Lc2VNZtUvnWEEusrQbgpuSxtUY0slYlte3XVDU2Rni3kdHfty1b2bq5liXHZK931S9S9pyIj7If796CvBDctDNSlvjlhdpzQWC5YfKmiiDC9j0tYDLVpupuVht3xSU2U3TdRBnNVxv1WaR5L8K3jL7i5QrTOT0x6636/B3/m/lDzvNfUp67NZmnWy6mTM4A2YxFMenj85/mLkL6lQiP2lhRyvRe1jGamFPvMPAH1tnV4qhA1m53XLIz3RpYfbtXt6bkZcAvqMQmX4Ks4xdAAEIZCf8CU1AJsvrcC2goNwqQgC5APcMkPayaLjp/ueBHpvQFZf1xBXiURiyExTFfSIvGW4l6RUowEO/oUz5uXK39hUdPq6AC6A5@touAgR0kEAw0KvNzLZkB6NtPrFIm3UjUbFIRZ1IQMGEDg4XwhQSZQEl42S6CJcWUUzF/cW6J6hIZ7DFNG3JSoi/gN9rHI0dkMuaOS4H/Qh1R6R0IgIczkHsQaYJ@RDVuBIgGzZODJlEZkxiktgssFAzowgON90U@qfnwr92PcoWxY58hvMRK1Mwt1EOYId1fga39xmuSQNEnqYkCmuO3n4mu3WXJJ1c/2qqJTFSB/pyAfo6bz3A4BDzHZwhV9IbmYUN9zUxLM10mvZNduKv@Y8y6o6@P4G3ahU1c1hxarh/Y9hcp@riHj9GsXAsclOqK2fFkP9lMNJIxxOUOlifJ5KOr2aR/pHSE6Xc1/U/dKjzNmkB@H5kI65fya6wLmqBkkn8WQZM3sy/U9fjUThXhqA0rTHVp4DgOzoFB8BoVL69hi369P7@GD7Dw/eZ4gXwd/m1A6fsYJsHAEjbdoWEztk@isKUB96/s8BnN@Q13TTvBqJcwqDJQE6RPzyQIzGKRIaMCcq47YfO4JlVdhcryknOG9fTyoUqlOpAej@iJQdsUnuxc0tk5ORf5ePQ3Juyut/OMXT05USYlSQmcFXlvcuMjBpEUODiaTgSKQj3Ka5xLCDiop82GqhnIHVUVymnClWH36oQvE7ESw@Z9//btZzDumyoDyvFhn6IJdVRlAzVC3S4usp4ZQwmVUoqQcqB@TdEREaeJ0ev3y0I9Er5wJf/NiEFru0CIwV06ZoAXvADymuVIutNttiGPy8OTRYwIRDY9Nu6oW6vA4ABmg9oXu57H1OruDDf1KdZomDvJByNLR4POjUiVIgS4dfX40GNf80CJSV8Zr7lRpqgS0cS4J2UZ7C/2CwK8en/712VlB4EJ0pkpVn6Bxpe1ms/n@9PS7qDc8Ohx3evPmYthvj96dfkOhbiN/ZzwKTu/746tTyDyn9zvvob9Zp7xfrBaN/wI)

```
SSQ        { Get one line of input }
l0=        { Is the program empty? }
2+].       { If so, halt (-1 -- True -> 1, move IP to `.`; 0 -- False -> 2, move IP past `.`) }
0g         { Pop first element from program, pushing to the stack }
'h=        { Is equal to 'h'? }

1-[{ ... } { If so, }
    SHello, WorldS? { Print "Hello World" }
    c]              { Skip 12 chars forward (loops back to start of program, skipping `SSQ`) }
            { Else }
    SerrS?          { Print "err" }
    .               { Halt }
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>85</s> 78 bytes

```rust
|n:&str|for c in n.chars(){if c=='h'{print!("Hello World")}else{todo!("err")}}
```

[Try it on Rust Playground!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c4689c83316b710df762f74459d6a79f)

I tried to get clever with rust iterators and `map_while`, but it ended up being much more golfy to just do a boring for loop :(

Even pattern matching is longer...

`todo!(err)` is a macro that always panics with the message `not yet implemented: err`, the key difference being that `todo!` is 1 byte shorter than `panic!`, the standard panic macro.

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 43 bytes

```julia
~=length
!x=x!="h"^~x?:err:"Hello World"^~x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/@/zjYnNS@9JINLscK2QtFWKUMprq7C3iq1qMhKySM1JydfITy/KCcFJPrfoTgjv1xBUSkjIzNDiQvOQ2JmIHE8lP4DAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
U'h=?{kh£}:`~Ɱ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWG0PVM2ztq7MzDi2utUqoe7Rx3ZLipORiqOyCpRkgAOEAAA)

##### Explanation

```python
U'h=?{kh£}:`~Ɱ  '# Implicit input
U                # Uniquify the input
 'h=?           '# If it equals "h":
     {   }       #   Length of input times:
      kh£        #     Print "Hello World"
                 #   No implicit output
          :      # Otherwise:
           `~Ɱ   #   Push compressed string "Error"
                 #   Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some different approaches I tried.

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 57 bytes

```python
lambda s:"Hello World"*(x:=s.count("h"))+"err"*(len(s)-x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PycxNyklUaHYSskjNScnXyE8vygnRUlLo8LKtlgvOb80r0RDKUNJU1NbKbWoCCiek5qnUaypW6H5/z8A)

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 60 bytes

```python
lambda s:"err"if(x:=s.count("h"))!=len(s)else"Hello World"*x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PycxNyklUaHYSim1qEgpM02jwsq2WC85vzSvREMpQ0lTU9E2JzVPo1gzNac4VckjNScnXyE8vygnRUmr4v9/AA)

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 63 bytes

```python
lambda s:"Hello World"*x if len(s)-(x:=s.count("h"))<1else"err"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PycxNyklUaHYSskjNScnXyE8vygnRUmrQiEzTSEnNU@jWFNXo8LKtlgvOb80r0RDKUNJU9PGMDWnOFUptahI6f9/AA)

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 66 bytes

```python
lambda s:eval("'err''Hello World'*x"[(x:=len(s)-s.count("h"))+5:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PycxNyklUaHYKrUsMUdDST21qEhd3SM1JydfITy/KCdFXatCKVqjwso2JzVPo1hTt1gvOb80r0RDKUNJU1Pb1CpW8/9/AA)

(Disclaimer: Does not work.)

I'm not sure if `1/0` is okay (it outputs a ZeroDivisionError) but if it is of course that would be bytes saved.

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 35 bytes

```
&p("err"|▽:"Hello World")≍⊙:↯:@h.⧻.
```

[Test pad](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__RiDihpAgJnAoImVyciJ84pa9OiJIZWxsbyBXb3JsZCIpbWF04oqZOuKGrzpAaC7ip7suCkYgImhoaGhoIgpGICJoZWxsbyIK)

Outputs to stdout for compliance with the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 33 bytes

```
|II^P[gn[^104/0]b"Hello World">]`
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7CII%5EP%5Bgn%5B%5E104%2F0%5Db%22Hello%20World%22%3E%5D%60&inputs=hhhhh)

Explanation:

```
|                 take input
 I                split input to characters and store characters in consecutive memory slots
  I^              get length of input (put on top of the stack)
    P             set pointer to 0
     [...]`       repeat n times, where n is the top of the stack

g                 get the value at the pointer
 n                get the ASCII int value of the character
  [^104  ]        if not 104 (the ASCII value for 'h')
       /0         divide by 0 (shortest way to throw an error)

b"Hello World"    add "Hello World" to print buffer
              >   move pointer right
```

Answer (score 0):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)'s type system, 73 bytes

```typescript
type F<S>=S extends`h${infer S}`?`Hello World${F<S>}`:S extends""?S:"err"
```

[Try it at the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPAZQHwF4FQgD2BAdgEwGcADACwBIBvAS1wDMIAnKBAX2IH5iAJCAGz4B7KAHVBjPvirxk7AFzosOAoQBEqjgjmqmjVQCh9oSFAAqEQsACMUFLDirST1Un0B6N1C8A9DkfDQ5pYATLb2ji7unj5+xoEWwADMYfDqrh5eUL7+JkHAACwpDowArgBGZdSEpJEZMTnxlgCsRY4lNenRWX5AA)

TypeScript's type system is well suited for tasks like this.

This version hits the recursion limit for strings longer than 50 characters. Here's an alternate version, using tail-recursion to increase the limit from 50 to 999:

### [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)'s type system, 93 bytes

```typescript
//@ts-ignore
type F<S,O="">=S extends`h${infer S}`?F<S,`${O}Hello World`>:S extends""?O:"err"
```

[Try it at the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=81&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTACBcGcFoEsHMB2B7ATgUwFDgJ4Ad0ACAMQB4BlAGgHkBeAInoD5bzD0APcdRAE0gAGACwAkAb1iIAZulSFyAXwEB+MlQHjqCgBLoANnuSEA6mj28BTAFxtO3PpEbLqV+rNT1M2fEQAq6SHAARkJaElJ6ISjmTBBCeIA9ZW8CQn9AgCZQ8MiYuMTk3FT08ABmbLJGJljgeMIklL8A8AAWCojUAFcAI27YSCE82oLGtOaAVnbIzsHq-PrkoA)

Answer (score 0):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/YASEPL-esolang/), 60 bytes

```
=b=1'=c®1`1!d¥b,1}7,"h",8!+}2,c;"Hello World",c<|9`8>"err"`9
```

### explanation

```
=b=1'=c®1`1!d¥b,1}7,"h",8!+}2,c;"Hello World",c<|9`8>"err"`9      packed
=b                                                                declare increment variable "b"
  =1'                                                             get user input and set it to variable "1"
     =c®1                                                         get length of variable 1 and set it to "c"
         `1                }2,c                                   while b < c...
           !d¥b,1                                                 get a character from variable 1 at index b and set it to "d"
                 }7,"h",8                         `8              if d is equal to "h"...
                         !+                                       add one to b.
                                                    >"err"        ...else, escape loop, error and quit
                               ;"Hello World",c<                  repeat "Hello World" c times once done checking if everything is "h" and print it
                                                |9                go to the end of the program
                                                          `9      end of the program
```

(im trying my best to format the explanation like how other people are. if it doesnt make sense tell me)